# Convert ContentAlignment to StringAlignment

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, button, alignment

I want to modify a Button, but have some difficulty in setting its text alignment correctly. Its text alignment is expressed using the `ContentAlignment` enumeration, so I have:

```
Private goTextAlign As ContentAlignment

Public Overrides Property TextAlign As ContentAlignment
    Get
        Return goTextAlign
    End Get
    Set(oValue As ContentAlignment)
        If oValue <> goTextAlign Then
            goTextAlign = oValue
            Me.Invalidate()     'Causes a paint message.
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

There's also a Text property. There are no issues with this one, what I enter in the properties window appears properly on the button, it is just provided for completeness:

```
<Category("Appearance")>
Public Overrides Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return gsText
    End Get
    Set(ByVal sValue As String)
        If sValue <> gsText Then    'If the new text differs from the old
            gsText = sValue         'one indeed, store it.
            Me.Invalidate()         'Invalidate causes a paint message to be 
        End If                      'sent to the control.
    End Set
End Property
```

Now, when it comes to painting, I've get a problem. I understand, that I can not use `ContentAlignment` with `DrawString`, but need to create a `StringFormat` object.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim sSaveText As String         
    Dim oTextAlign As ContentAlignment
    sSaveText = Me.Text             'Save the current text.
    oTextAlign = Me.TextAlign
    gsText = String.Empty           'Blank the Text property.
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)               'Erase the client area.
    gsText = sSaveText              'Restore the Text property.
    goTextAlign = oTextAlign

    Using oBrush = New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
        Using oStringFormat = New StringFormat()
```

How do I extract and convert from goTextAlign?

```
            oStringFormat.Alignment = ?
            oStringFormat.LineAlignment = ?

            e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, oBrush,
                Rectangle.Inflate(ClientRectangle, 0, 0), oStringFormat)
        End Using                  
    End Using                       
End Sub
```

Of course, I could use a constant there:

```
        Using oStringFormat = New StringFormat() With
            {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center}
```

But this is not what I want, I want to use the values provided in goTextAlign.

Of course, I could do a Select catching all 3 x 3 possibilities from goTextAlign and assign the appropriate values to .Alignment and .LineAlignment, but there ought to be a more concise solution for this conversion.

So the question is: **How do I convert ContentAlignment so, that StringFormat is happily accepting them?**

---

For completeness, the Class definition:

```
'In order to see the Text property in the appearance section of the properties 
'window, the Category attribute needs to be modified, which requires the 
'inclusion of the ComponentModel namespace.
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class FlatButton
    Inherits Button

    ...
End Class
```

---

Edit: this works, but it's ugly.

```
        Using oStringFormat = New StringFormat()
            'There surely is a more concise way of doing this?
            Select Case goTextAlign
                Case ContentAlignment.TopLeft
                    oStringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
                    oStringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                Case ContentAlignment.TopCenter
                    oStringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
                    oStringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                Case ContentAlignment.TopRight
                    oStringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
                    oStringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                Case ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
                    oStringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    oStringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                Case ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                    oStringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    oStringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                Case ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                    oStringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    oStringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                Case ContentAlignment.BottomLeft
                    oStringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far
                    oStringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                Case ContentAlignment.BottomCenter
                    oStringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far
                    oStringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                Case ContentAlignment.BottomRight
                    oStringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far
                    oStringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
            End Select

            'Draw the string contained in Text with the acquired brush in the
            'acquired string format, in the button's client rectangle, which 
            'is enlarged by 3 pixels in each direction. The original client
            'rectangle has a padding of 3 pixels to allow for a 2 pixels wide
            'border (3D), and a 1-pixel margin between the border and the 
            'actual text.
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, oBrush,
                Rectangle.Inflate(ClientRectangle, 3, 3), oStringFormat)
        End Using                   'Dispose the StringFormat object.
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that your question isn't forgotten or ignored. I'm currently at work, but during the breaks I'm trying to find a good mathematical relationship between the two enumerations. Hopefully I'll find one. :)

Comment: `I understand, that I can not use ContentAlignment with DrawString...`  You should probably be using TextRender instead

Comment: @Plutonix, thanks for your suggestion, I will look into it. I'm just wondering... VB.Net does have a Button property TextAlign accepting a ContentAlignment value. But also, there is a Button event to redraw it. How is TextAlign in the original Button class evaluated?

Comment: Its not straight forward - most controls you see inherit from a  `...Base` object like `TextBoxBase` or `ButtonBase` since those are used elsewhere like ComboBox and NumericUpDown.  There are Adapters and Renderers to draw things correctly given the context.  There isnt a 1:1 relationship between ContentAligment and StringFormat.  And if you use TextRenderer, you use TextFormatFlags anyway

Comment: @Plutonix : `There isnt a 1:1 relationship between ContentAligment and StringFormat.` - There is now. ;) (enumeration-wise at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some trial and error I managed to come up with a purely mathematical solution both for the horizontal and vertical alignment. These are probably the hardest and definitely the most complicated ways of doing it, but they can be written in one line of code each.

**NOTE:** This is just a workaround and was created in order to use as few lines of code as possible ***and*** remove the "need" for repeating code. There is no official conversion between `ContentAlignment` and `StringAlignment`.

Full solution for both horizontal and vertical can be found in the bottom.

### Horizontal solution (explanation)

After running this code [(online)](http://ideone.com/CpDmZN):

```
Console.WriteLine("-- ContentAlignment --")
For Each Name As String In [Enum].GetNames(GetType(System.Drawing.ContentAlignment))
    Console.WriteLine(Name & ": " & CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(System.Drawing.ContentAlignment), Name), Integer))
Next

Console.WriteLine()
Console.WriteLine("-- StringAlignment --")

For Each Name As String In [Enum].GetNames(GetType(System.Drawing.StringAlignment))
    Console.WriteLine(Name & ": " & CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(System.Drawing.StringAlignment), Name), Integer))
Next
```

I found out what values the enumerations had:

```
-- ContentAlignment --
TopLeft: 1
TopCenter: 2
TopRight: 4
MiddleLeft: 16
MiddleCenter: 32
MiddleRight: 64
BottomLeft: 256
BottomCenter: 512
BottomRight: 1024

-- StringAlignment --
Near: 0
Center: 1
Far: 2
```

Now I just had to find a way to turn every `Left` into 0, `Center` into 1 and `Right` into 2.

So by some (not so random) trial and error I came up with this formula:

```
Log(x Mod 5, 2)
```

- `x Mod 5` will return a value between 0 and 4 (a great explanation of how modulo works can be found at [**Khan Academy (Modular Arithmetic)**](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic)).
- `Log(x Mod 5, 2)` will return the logarithm of `x Mod 5` in base 2, which is `n` in `2n = x Mod 5` (again, [**Khan Academy (Intro to Logarithms)**](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/exponential-and-logarithmic-functions/introduction-to-logarithms/a/intro-to-logarithms) explains it very well).

Since `x Mod 5` can only be whole numbers in the range 0-4, `Log(x Mod 5, 2)` can only return an exponent (`n`) in the range 0-2 (`22 = 4`).

Now since the `ContentAlignment` enumeration consists only of binary numbers, `n` in `2n` will always be a whole number, thus 0, 1 or 2 - which is exactly what we need since the `StringAlignment` enumeration only has those three values. **Problem solved!**

**Online test:** http://ideone.com/XKqeFw

```
'Horizontal version only. See the bottom of this answer for full code covering both horizontal and vertical.
Public Function ContentToStringAlignment(ByVal Alignment As ContentAlignment) As StringAlignment
    Return CType(Math.Log(CType(Alignment, Integer) Mod 5, 2), StringAlignment)
End Function
```

### Vertical solution (explanation)

The vertical solution is, in my opinion, a little more "hackish", but it works.

Since the vertical solution is a little harder due to that there are whole ranges (e.g. 16-64) that are of the same alignment, I figured the easiest way would be if I could somehow get a decimal number that is **greater than or equal to** the wanted alignment, then round that down.

This was the formula I came up with:

```
Floor(Log(x, 16))
```

- `Log(x, 16)` will return the logarithm of `x` in base `16`, thus `n` in `16n = x`.
  For binary numbers `n` will be a whole number and 0-2 quarters (e.g. `1`, `1.25`, `1.5`, etc.).
- `Floor(Log(x, 16))` will return the result of `Log(x, 16)` ***rounded down*** (e.g. `1.5 -> 1`).

The formula will result in three following binary numbers returning the same number.

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|   Binary   |  Log(x, 16)  | Floor(Log(x, 16)) |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
| 256        | 2            | 2                 |
| 512        | 2.25         | 2                 |
| 1024       | 2.50         | 2                 |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

**Online test:** http://ideone.com/yIlrJS

### Final solution

Finally, with this information we can now create a relatively small function which does the wanted conversion for us:

```
Public Function ContentToStringAlignment(ByVal Alignment As ContentAlignment, ByVal Vertical As Boolean) As StringAlignment
    If Vertical = True Then Return CType(Math.Floor(Math.Log(CType(Alignment, Integer), 16)), StringAlignment)
    Return CType(Math.Log(CType(Alignment, Integer) Mod 5, 2), StringAlignment)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
oStringFormat.LineAlignment = ContentToStringAlignment(goTextAlign, True) 'True for vertical alignment.
oStringFormat.Alignment = ContentToStringAlignment(goTextAlign, False)
```

**Online test:** http://ideone.com/VFN8rS

Answer (score 2):

### A better answer not using logarithms

This is assuming there is exactly one bit set in the ControlAlignment, but then the solutions using Math.Log have troubles with multi-bit values as well.

This is all in C# syntax, sorry for that... I also hope these didn't lose anything in the transcription into this posting.

Assuming `ca` is the initial `ContentAlignment` value, represented as a hex number it would have the form `0xBMT` where B, M, and T stand for Bottom, Middle, and Top and each of these has the binary form `0RCL` where R, C, L mean Right (Far), Center, and Left (Near)

### Extracting Horizontal Alignment

```
(StringAlignment)((((int)ca * 0x111) >> 9) & 0x3)
```

The multiplication by `0x111` adds (and thus ORs, being a single bit) the B, M, and T values together in the B position. The right shift of 9 turns the B position into a binary number of the form `RC`, having value 2, 1, or 0. The final & operation removes junk above the B position that was created by the multiplication.

### Extracting Vertical Alignment

```
(StringAlignment)((((((int)ca * 7) & 0x444) * 0x49) >> 9) & 0x3)
```

The multiplication by 7 adds (and thus ORs, being a single bit) the RCL bits into the R position within each of the BMT hex digits. ANDing with `0x444` keeps only the R bits (which are now the OR of R, C, and L) in each of the BMT hex digits. Multiplication by `0x49` puts copies of the R bits of the M and T groups just below that of the B group. The shift and & do the same as in extracting horizontal alignment.

### Replacing Horizontal Alignment with `ta`

```
(ContentAlignment)((0x111 << (int)ta) & (((((int)ca * 7) & 0x444) * 7) >> 2))
```

The result is produced by masking the new horizontal alignment for all vertical alignments with the original vertical alignment for all horizontal alignments. The first term takes BMT bits for the L position and shifts them to L, C, or R depending on the new alignment. The second term mashes L, C, and R together into the R position for each of B, M, and T, cleans up junk by ANDing with `0x444`, multiplies by 7 and shifts down by two to produce all L, C, and R on in the appropriate BMT group.

### Replacing Vertical Alignment with `ta`

```
(ContentAlignment)((0x7 << (4 * (int)ta)) & (((((int)ca * 0x111) & 0x700) * 0x111) >> 8))
```

Analogous to the horizontal case, the first term generates all of L, C, and R positioned appropriately for the desired vertical alignment. The second term mashes together B, M, and T for each of the LCR bits into the LCR of the B group. ANDing with `0x700` keeps just the B group, and multiplication by `0x111` and right shift of 8 produce the original L, C, or R bit duplicated in all three BMT groups.

Comment: I haven't seen your answer until now! It's quite an interesting solution you've got there! Originally I was trying to do it the binary/hex way as well, but I'm unfortunately not as much into binary math as I am with regular math ;). Well done!

Comment: The vertical part is good to go, but the horizontal seems not. For example, `BottomCenter` is 512, `(512 * 0x111 >> 7) / 3` is 364

Comment: J.C - Indeed. In the process of correcting this I noticed that division by 3 was a clumsy way of converting 8, 4, and 2 into 2, 1, 0 when shifting down two bits would work just as well. The updated definitions are `(StringAlignment)((((int)ca * 0x111) >> 9) & 0x3)` for extracting horizontal alignment and `(StringAlignment)((((((int)ca * 7) & 0x444) * 0x49) >> 9) & 0x3)` for vertical

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Dictionary<ContentAlignment, StringFormat> dictAlign = new Dictionary<ContentAlignment, StringFormat>()  {
    { ContentAlignment.TopLeft, new StringFormat{ LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near, Alignment = StringAlignment.Near } },
    { ContentAlignment.TopCenter, new StringFormat{ LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near, Alignment = StringAlignment.Center } },
    { ContentAlignment.TopRight, new StringFormat{ LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near, Alignment = StringAlignment.Far } },
    { ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, new StringFormat{ LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center, Alignment = StringAlignment.Near } },
    { ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, new StringFormat{ LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center, Alignment = StringAlignment.Center } },
    { ContentAlignment.MiddleRight, new StringFormat{ LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center, Alignment = StringAlignment.Far } },
    { ContentAlignment.BottomLeft, new StringFormat{ LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far, Alignment = StringAlignment.Near } },
    { ContentAlignment.BottomCenter, new StringFormat{ LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far, Alignment = StringAlignment.Center } },
    { ContentAlignment.BottomRight, new StringFormat{ LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far, Alignment = StringAlignment.Far } },
};
```

Then to use:

```
StringFormat sf = dictAlign[TextAlign];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).